# Plain mirror reflection confusion

Tags: reflection, mirror-symmetry

Can anybody help me reconcile my understanding of plain mirror reflection with what is said in this video?

[instagram video](https://www.instagram.com/reel/C0J_cE8rQ9I/?igshid=MTc4MmM1YmI2Ng==)

My understanding is that image size is always the same as object size but in this video he seems to suggest image size is half. Unless I am misunderstanding something he is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see how the video is a bit confusing, but near the end he says "... making it (the image) half the size you would be if you were *at the mirror*."

So your image is the same size as you but because it's twice as far away as the mirror it appears half the size that it would at the distance of the mirror.

I'm not sure how important or even interesting that observation is but that's the point the presenter is making.

Comment: Thank you. As I posted it I think I realised what he was saying but as with most things involving physics, a second opinion is always nice :). I agree too, not sure how interesting it is but might sound good to casual viewers?